# keep scroll position after location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I ues ajax to update the chosen photo.
if sucess,then refresh the page ,and user can see the chosen image (it will have a css border)
But when the page refresh,The position will back to the top.
I want to know how to maintain the position after reload ?

I search many websites and still can't get it .

Please guide me a bit  Thank you.

**EDIT:** 
I found the answer here!!

`http://www.bkjia.com/Javascript/826924.html`

Comment: this may be too much, but store it as a cookie?

Comment: store what as a cookie??

Comment: Thank you @user3743069. I found the answer which uses cookie